# Using Font Awesome with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

A Major problem I found while developing with Bootstrap 4 and trying to create a Font Awesome button that when I create a series of buttons, I get different size buttons, the only way to get the same size buttons is to use the same font for each one So the problem is due to Font Awesome sizes is not the same for every one.

```
      <a class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="button" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </a>

      <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" type="button" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </a>
```

Does one have a practical exemple to get Off this problem ?

Comment: @Craig: I think that my question do not deserve to be negative rated, because it's about a real problem that many people will get.

Comment: The down vote was given by another user.  I only added an additional Tag, 'css', to help your question reach more people.  The following resource, will help you to improve your questions and help reduce your Down Votes ... https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

While you can certainly manually adjust the font size of your Font Awesome icons, I would suggest a less dramatic approach: `.fa-fw`.  This is a utility class that is part of Font Awesome's stylesheet that helps unify the width of your fonts.  Per the 4.7.0 documentation:

> Use `fa-fw` to set icons at a fixed width. Great to use when different
>   icon widths throw off alignment. Especially useful in things like nav
>   lists & list groups.

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i>
</a>

<br>

<a class="btn btn-outline-danger" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i>
</a>

<br>

<a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-wrench"></i>
</a>

<br>

<a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-stop"></i>
</a>
```

In the above example you can see how `.fa-fw` has adjusted your icon spacing and everything looks the same.  You might notice though that I did also remove `type="button"` from your anchor tag as this was resulting in Bootstrap not applying the full CSS of the `ban-outline-*` you were declaring.

Answer (score 0):

As their name suggests, their icons are nothing more than 'glorified' Fonts.  As such, you are able to modify their sizes using inline CSS; or better still, via an external CSS Stylesheet.

You can modify the `fa` class by entering:

```
.fa{
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

Simply change the `15px` to whatever is appropriate.  As well as using `px` you can also use `em`.  Also, ensure you include `!important` as to override Bootstrap's CSS Stylesheet entry.

You can also modify the specific icon/font by entering the specific class, as follows:

```
fa fa-edit{
    font-size: 15px !important;
}
```

If you are your own Theme's Author, I am sure you are aware of how Stylesheets work as well as priorities etc.  If not, then you should first create a [Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and then modify the Child Theme only.  If you modify the Parent theme, then your modifications will be overridden when the Theme Author releases an update.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to the size:

> https://fontawesome.com/icons?from=io

and choose icon and read usage icon